# Helm upgrade with same chart version, but different Docker image tag

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a question about a Helm upgrade. I'm working on a chart foo-1.0.0 which deploys a pod with a docker image bar:4.5.1.

I have a release "myrelease" based on this chart foo in version 1.0.0 (with a bar:4.5.1 running inside).

Now, I make a fix on bar, rebuild the image **bar:4.5.2**, change the image in the chart but I did not bump its version. It is still foo-1.0.0

I launch:

```
$ helm upgrade myrelease repo/foo --version 1.0.0
```

My problem is that after the upgrade, my pod is still running the bar:4.5.1 instead the 4.5.2

Is the a "cache" in tiller? It seems that tiller did not download foo-1.0.0 again. Is there a way to force it to download?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to change the `tag` version in the image section of  `values.yaml`:

```
image:
  repository: bar
  tag: 4.5.2
  pullPolicy: Always
```

and then run the following command:

```
helm upgrade myrelease repo/foo
```

or just run the following:

```
helm upgrade myrelease repo/foo --set=image.tag=1.2.2
```

and set the applicable image version.

Comment: Note I had to delete the deployment with kubectl before running helm upgrade, due to the selector labels being updated by the helm upgrade, which is an immutable field and not possible while the previous deployment is still running.